# Writing "Hello World" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to write a few Unix scripts in Emacs Lisp.  However, there doesn't seem to be a clean way to write to STDOUT so I can redirect the results to a file or pipe the output to another command.  The **print** function places double quotes around the output strings so I get **"Hello world!"** instead of **Hello world!**.

Here's the emacs script.

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
;;
;; Run me from a Unix shell: ./hello.el > x.txt
;;
(message "Hello world!  I'm writing to STDERR.")
(print "Hello world!  I'm writing to STDOUT but I'm in quotes")
(insert "Hello world!  I'm writing to an Emacs buffer")
(write-file "y.txt")
```

And here's how I would like to call it.

```
hello.el > x.txt
hello.el | wc
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seems like you want `princ` instead of `print`. So, basically:

`(princ "Hello world!  I'm writing to STDOUT but I'm not in quotes!")`

However, one caveat is that `princ` does not automatically terminate the output with `\n`.

Comment: Yikes, I forgot about princ.  I actually used it a several months ago in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532311/cgi-programming-in-elisp

Answer (score 7):

As David Antaramian says, you probably want `princ`.

Also, `message` supports a format control string (akin to `printf` in C) that is adapted from `format`. So, you may eventually want to do something like

```
(princ (format "Hello, %s!\n" "World"))
```

As a couple of functions plus demonstration:

```
(defun fmt-stdout (&rest args)
  (princ (apply 'format args)))
(defun fmtln-stdout (&rest args)
  (princ (apply 'format
                (if (and args (stringp (car args)))
                    (cons (concat (car args) "\n") (cdr args))
                  args))))

(defun test-fmt ()
  (message "Hello, %s!" "message to stderr")
  (fmt-stdout "Hello, %s!\n" "fmt-stdout, explict newline")
  (fmtln-stdout "Hello, %s!" "fmtln-stdout, implicit newline"))
```