# awk '{print $2,",",$1}' in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: awk, elisp

Occasionally I use AWK to extract and/or reverse columns in a data file.

```
awk '{print $2,",",$1}' filename.txt
```

How would I do the same using Emacs Lisp?

```
(defun awk (filename col1 &optional col2 col3 col4 col5)
  "Given a filename and at least once column, print out the column(s)
values in the order in which the columns are specified."
...
)
;; Test awk
(awk "filename.txt" 1); Only column 1
(awk "filename.txt" 2 1); Column 2 followed by column 1
(awk "filename.txt" 3 2 1); Columns 3,2 then 1
```

Sample `filename.txt`:

```
a   b  c
1   2  5
```

Sample output:

```
b , a
2 , 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you intend to use this?  Are you planning on using it as a command-line script?  In which case, you'll need to package it like this [hello world question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170528/writing-hello-world-in-emacs).

Or, are you planning on using it interactively, in which case you probably want the output in a new buffer...

This code gets the basics done.  You'll need to update it to match your usage model.

```
(defun awk (filename &rest cols)
  "Given a filename and at least once column, print out the column(s) values
in the order in which the columns are specified."
  (let* ((buf (find-file-noselect filename)))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (while (< (point) (point-max))
        (let ((things (split-string (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
              (c cols)
              comma)
          (while c
            (if comma
                (print ", "))
            (print (nth (1- (car c)) things))
            (setq comma t)
            (setq c (cdr c)))
          (print "\n")
          (forward-line))))
    (kill-buffer buf)))
```

Comment: I've heard that `with-current-buffer` should be used instead of `save-excursion` and `set-buffer`.

Comment: Why are you printing the newline after each column? Surely you mean to print it after printing all the selected columns from a line?

Answer (score 0):

I took Trey's solution and produced a script that runs from a Unix shell.  It doesn't take command line parameters because I wasn't sure how to convert the **command-line-args-left** results into a proper parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

;; ./awk.el; # Change the last line of this file to contain the desired values.
;;
(defun awk (filename &rest cols)
  "Given a filename and at least once column, print out the column(s) values
in the order in which the columns are specified."
  (let* ((buf (find-file-noselect filename)))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (while (< (point) (point-max))
        (let ((things (split-string (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) 
                          (line-end-position))))
              (c cols)
              comma)
          (while c
            (if comma
                (princ ", "))
            (princ (nth (1- (car c)) things))
            (setq comma t)
            (setq c (cdr c)))
            (princ "\n")
          (forward-line))))
    (kill-buffer buf)))

(awk "/tmp/foo.txt" 2 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions from [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el):

```
(defun print-columns (s &rest is)
  (s-join "\n"
          (--map (s-join ", "
                         (-select-by-indices is (cons it (s-split " " it t))))
                 (s-lines s))))

(print-columns "a  b c\n1  2 3" 3 2 1 0) ; output:
;; c, b, a, a  b c
;; 3, 2, 1, 1  2 3
```

By default, awk treats text as a sequence of records (separated by newline), each record being a sequence of fields (separated by space). So in the above example `c` is a field of the record `a  b c`. The function `print-columns` receives a text, separates by newlines with [`s-lines`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-lines-s), selects certain fields from each record, joins them with a comma with [`s-join`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-join-separator-strings), joins the result with newlines. The most important function is `dash`'s [`-select-by-indices`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-select-by-indices-indices-list), which picks elements from a list by their indexes and returns in the same order as the list of indices:

```
(-select-by-indices '(2 1 0) '(a b c d e)) ; => (c b a)
```